# Horizontally combine two 2D arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to combine two 2D arrays a, b horizontally such that if:

```
a = [[1, 1],
     [1, 1]]
b = [[2, 2],
     [2, 2]]
```

then the merged array c should look like:

```
c = [[1, 1, 2, 2],
     [1, 1, 2, 2]]
```

It is very simple to vertically combine then to look like this:

```
d = [[1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [2, 2],
     [2, 2]]
```

but I want to horizontally combine them. Any idea on how to accomplish this for two 2D arrays that have the same dimension?

Comment: Show us how you create `d` from `a` and `b`, then explain to us why you can't use the same type of logic for creating `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimensions of the arrays a and b are the same (i.e. for some positive integers x and y):

```
int[][] a = new int[x][y];
int[][] b = new int[x][x];
```

then create a new array as:

```
int[][] c = new int[2*x][y];
```

and use nested for loops to fill-in the corresponding elements:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] a = {{1,1},{1,1}};
            int[][] b = {{2,2},{2,2}};

        int[][] c = new int[2*a.length][a.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < 2*a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (i < a.length) {
                    c[i][j] = a[i][j];
                } else {
                    c[i][j] = b[i - a.length][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```